# NGINX configures front-end routing,404 cannot be returned

Tags: reactjs, nginx, web, webserver

Ask a question, deploy React project with nginx, in order to configure the front-end routing of React Router, use $try_files for nginx to locate all routes into index.html, but there is a problem with this configuration,If you want to request other files, such as *.json, *.md, and if I request the json file in the directory, If the json file does not exist, the server will directly return the index.html file instead of returning 404. How to solve it?

```
location / {
    alias /usr/local/var/www/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[By default it looks like this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

You don't need that `index.html` in try_files, since you have it as `index` option value.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file you have set for NGINX is always going to fall back to index.html, as it will attempt to match try_files in order. What you need to add is `=404;` or better yet, change:

```
try_files $uri index.html;
```

to the implementation found in user973254s answer. Otherwise, NGINX is always going to fall back to `index.html`.

Please see https://serverfault.com/questions/329592/how-does-try-files-work for a pretty detailed explanation. It directly addresses an instance where you append =404; to the try_files directive.

(Asked To Answer Via Queue)